# Rsync's rolling checksum in haskell

Tags: haskell, checksum

I'm starting learn both haskell and remote delta compression. My first step is to implement rsync's version of [rolling checksum](http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/node3.html) in haskell. Does chunk equal to `X(i)` in those formula? If so I'm getting confused.

- Haskell can turn bytestring into byte array
- How I do turn array of `Word8`s into that big chunk. `Word32768`? I mean what if `X(i)` is list of `Word8`s?
- After that how to do arithmetical operation on those `unsigned int`s of 4KB size?

Also my current version of implementation just slides by 1B (Word8) each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's very easy to turn a `ByteString` into `[Word8]` using `unpack`, which should be sufficient for performing this algorithm (although not necessarily the most efficient).
2. Why do you need to turn `Word8`s into a `Word32768`?  Why do you need a `2^15` bit number?  That would be very difficult to represent, but you could use a list or array of `Word8`s, which is very easy to represent in memory and is equivalent.
3. For performing arithmetic, functions like `map`, `zipWith`, `fold`s, and `scan`s are very useful.  For example, performing the first step of the algorithm:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

a :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> Int
a k l x
    = (`mod` m)
    $ sum
    $ map fromIntegral
    $ take (l - k)
    $ drop k
    $ BS.unpack x
    where m = 2 ^ 16
```

And implementing the function `b` is only marginally more difficult, you just have to figure out the sequence of `l - i + 1` for `i = k` to `l`, then use `zipWith (*)` between the `map fromIntegral` and `take (l - k)`.  After that, it's quite trivial to implement `s`, although it certainly could be performed more efficiently if you factor out the common steps of `take (l - k) $ drop k $ BS.unpack x`.

Comment: what if `X(i)` is list of `Word8`s? or `ByteString`

Comment: `BS.unpack :: ByteString -> [Word8]`, so you can just drop that part and have `drop k x` if `x :: [Word8]`.

Comment: @DulguunLst I'm not sure what you mean by "if `X(i)` is a `ByteString`".  Are you saying that you want to perform this operation on chunks of `ByteString`s at a time?  The algorithm is designed for performing math on `Word8`s, but if you want to treat a `ByteString` as a single number you're probably better off converting to `Integer`, as it's unbounded and has all your instances already defined.

Comment: In this blog post he was talking about window size https://moinakg.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/inside-content-defined-chunking-in-pcompress/ which I understand. Then in here he talked about chunks of 4KB, 8KB etc. https://moinakg.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/inside-content-defined-chunking-in-pcompress/. And I thought chunk is X(i).

Comment: Window is `X(k),X(k+1),...,X(l)`. Chunk is a single element from window. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DulguunLst That looks to be a compression algorithm, entirely different from a checksum algorithm.  It also appears to be a rather advanced method, and I can not recommend attempt to replicate it with only beginner Haskell knowledge (or for that matter beginner knowledge in any language).  What are you wanting to accomplish here?

Comment: Replicate Rsync in Haskell

Comment: @DulguunLst Then I would focus on simple tasks first, such as replicating the RSync rolling checksum algorithm, transferring a file, then start adding features like compression.  Remember that RSync is a rather complex program with many authors, and it's going to take a while for you to reach that sort of complexity, particularly if you're just beginning with Haskell; although this is true of any new language you might choose to use.  Remember that you can always come back and rewrite an algorithm to be more complex, but it's always easier to implement it for the simplest case first.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now :D. Rolling checksum. Already done rolling checksum.

Answer (score 2):

Chunk does not equal to X(i) in that equation/formula in the link provided. It is mostly related to `Data Deduplication`. Also, `rolling checksum` can be used to create chunks, identify chunk boundaries etc.

Also my current implementation of rsync's rolling checksum is as follows. Next I'm gonna implement cyclic polynomial rolling checksum then read some books on `Data Deduplication`

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Int

type CheckSumPartial = Word16
type CheckSumA = CheckSumPartial
type CheckSumB = CheckSumPartial
type WindowSize = Int64
type CheckSum = Word32
type Byte = Word8

main:: IO ()
main = do
  let str = B8.pack "abcdef"
  let s1 = roll 3 str
  let s2 = withoutRoll 3 str
  print s1
  print s2
  return ()

roll :: WindowSize -> B.ByteString -> [CheckSum]
roll w str = 
  let
    (a,b,s) = newABS w str
    h = B.head str
    t = B.tail str
  in if fromIntegral (B.length t) < w
        then [s]
        else s : rollNext w t h a b

withoutRoll :: WindowSize -> B.ByteString -> [CheckSum]
withoutRoll w str =
  let
    (_,_,s) = newABS w str
    t = B.tail str
  in if fromIntegral (B.length t) <  w
      then [s]
      else s : withoutRoll w t

newA :: WindowSize -> B.ByteString -> CheckSumA
newA w str = 
  let    block = B.take w str
  in B.foldr aSum (0::CheckSumA) block
  where
    aSum x acc = acc + (fromIntegral x :: CheckSumA)

newB :: WindowSize -> B.ByteString -> CheckSumB
newB w str = 
  let block = B.take w str
  in fst $ B.foldr bSum (0::CheckSumB, w) block
  where
    bSum x (acc,l) = (acc +  fromIntegral l * (fromIntegral x :: CheckSumB), l-1) 

rollA :: CheckSumA -> Byte -> Byte -> CheckSumA
rollA prevA prevHead curLast = prevA - fromIntegral prevHead + fromIntegral curLast

rollB :: CheckSumA -> Byte -> WindowSize -> CheckSumB -> CheckSumB
rollB curA prevHead w prevB = prevB - fromIntegral w * fromIntegral prevHead + curA

calculateS :: CheckSumA -> CheckSumB -> CheckSum
calculateS a b = (fromIntegral a :: Word32) .|. shift (fromIntegral b :: Word32) 16

rollNext :: WindowSize ->B.ByteString -> Byte -> CheckSumA -> CheckSumB -> [CheckSum]
rollNext w str prevHead prevA prevB =
  let
    curBlock = B.take (fromIntegral w) str
    curLast = B.last curBlock
    h = B.head str
    t = B.tail str
    a = rollA prevA prevHead curLast
    b = rollB a prevHead w prevB
    s = calculateS a b
  in if fromIntegral (B.length t) < w
      then [s]
      else s : rollNext w t h a b

newABS :: WindowSize -> B.ByteString -> (CheckSumA, CheckSumB, CheckSum)
newABS w str =
  let a = newA w str
      b = newB w str
      s = calculateS a b
   in (a,b,s)
```